# Remove the "problem" word filter for users with 1000+ rep

Tags: feature-request

Question: [Why is the travelling salesman prob. NP-hard while the Hamiltonian path prob. is NP-complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646395/why-is-the-travelling-salesman-prob-np-hard-while-the-hamiltonian-path-prob-is)

I wanted to use the phrase "travelling salesman problem" and "Hamiltonian problem" in the title, but it said the word "problem" is not allowed. I think it is essential to use the word "problem" in my case.

Comment: That question would be a better fit for [cs.se](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Dupe on Meta.SE: [Let users with sufficient reputation use "problem" in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108815)